Pytorch mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (131072x12 and 64x32)
I have a multivariate time series forecasting model that originally used dilated temporal convolution for temporal dependencies extraction that i tried to replace with multi head self-attention with residual connection but when i try to train it on the PEMSD4 dataset i get this error RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (131072x12 and 64x32)
here's the model:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from graph_constuct_fgwn_2 import graph_constructor
from layer_mtgnn import *
import numpy as np
from DSTAGNN_my import MultiHeadAttention, ScaledDotProductAttention, Embedding

class dnconv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(dnconv, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x, A):
        if len(A.size()) == 2:
            A = A.unsqueeze(0).repeat(x.shape[0], 1, 1)
        x = torch.einsum('nvw, ncwl->ncvl', [A, x])
        return x.contiguous()

class linear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, c_in, c_out):
        super(linear, self).__init__()
        self.mlp = torch.nn.Conv2d(c_in, c_out, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding=(0, 0), stride=(1, 1), bias=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.mlp(x)

class gcn_modify(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, c_in, c_out, dropout, support_len=3, order=2):
        super(gcn_modify, self).__init__()
        self.nconv = dnconv()
        c_in = (order * support_len + 1) * c_in
        self.mlp = linear(c_in, c_out)
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.order = order

    def forward(self, x, support):
        out = [x]
        x1 = self.nconv(x, support)
        out.append(x1)
        for k in range(2, self.order + 1):
            x2 = self.nconv(x1, support)
            out.append(x2)
            x1 = x2

        h = torch.cat(out, dim=1)
        h = self.mlp(h)
        h = F.dropout(h, self.dropout, training=self.training)
        return h

class gwnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device, num_nodes, dropout=0.3, gcn_bool=True, addaptadj=True, seq_length=12,
                 in_dim=1, out_dim=12, residual_channels=32, dilation_channels=32, skip_channels=64, end_channels=128,
                 layers=2, embed_dim=10, dropout_ingc=0.5, eta=1, gamma=0.001,
                 m=0.9, highway=False, batch_size=64, tc_dropout=0.1, n_heads=8, d_model=64):
        super(gwnet, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.layers = layers
        self.gcn_bool = gcn_bool
        self.addaptadj = addaptadj

        self.filter_convs = nn.ModuleList()
        self.gate_convs = nn.ModuleList()
        self.residual_convs = nn.ModuleList()
        self.skip_convs = nn.ModuleList()
        self.bn = nn.ModuleList()
        self.gconv = nn.ModuleList()
        self.gconv_1 = nn.ModuleList()
        self.norm = nn.ModuleList()

        self.attention_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.n_heads = n_heads

        self.start_conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_dim,
                                    out_channels=residual_channels,
                                    kernel_size=(1, 1))
        self.seq_length = seq_length
        self.receptive_field = layers * 4 + 1

        self.temporal_embedding = Embedding(seq_length, d_model, residual_channels, 'T')

        for i in range(layers):
            self.attention_layers.append(
                MultiHeadAttention(device, d_model, d_model // n_heads, d_model // n_heads, n_heads, num_nodes)
            )

            self.residual_convs.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=d_model,
                                                 out_channels=residual_channels,
                                                 kernel_size=(1, 1)))
            
            if self.seq_length > self.receptive_field:
                self.skip_convs.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=d_model,
                                                 out_channels=skip_channels,
                                                 kernel_size=(1, self.seq_length - self.receptive_field + 1)))
            else:
                self.skip_convs.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=d_model,
                                                 out_channels=skip_channels,
                                                 kernel_size=(1, 1)))

            if self.gcn_bool:
                self.gconv.append(gcn_modify(d_model, residual_channels, dropout, support_len=1, order=2))
                self.gconv_1.append(gcn_modify(d_model, residual_channels, dropout, support_len=1, order=2))

            if self.seq_length > self.receptive_field:
                self.norm.append(LayerNorm((residual_channels, num_nodes, self.seq_length - self.receptive_field + 1),
                                           elementwise_affine=True))
            else:
                self.norm.append(LayerNorm((residual_channels, num_nodes, 1),
                                           elementwise_affine=True))

        self.end_conv_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=skip_channels,
                                    out_channels=end_channels,
                                    kernel_size=(1, 1),
                                    bias=True)

        self.end_conv_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=end_channels,
                                    out_channels=out_dim,
                                    kernel_size=(1, 1),
                                    bias=True)

        self.skip0 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_dim, out_channels=skip_channels, kernel_size=(1, 1), bias=True)
        self.skipE = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=residual_channels, out_channels=skip_channels, kernel_size=(1, 1), bias=True)

        self.idx = torch.arange(num_nodes).to(device)

        self.graph_construct = graph_constructor(num_nodes, embed_dim, device, seq_length, eta=eta, in_dim=in_dim,
                                                 gamma=gamma, dropout=dropout_ingc, m=m, batch_size=batch_size)

    def forward(self, input, pred_time_embed=None):
        in_len = input.size(3)
        if in_len < self.receptive_field:
            x = nn.functional.pad(input, [self.receptive_field - in_len, 0, 0, 0])
        else:
            x = input

        new_supports = None
        gl_loss = None
        dy_adj = None
        adj_norm = None
        if self.gcn_bool:
            adp, resolution_static, node_embed, gl_loss_from, dy_nodeEmbed, adj_norm = self.graph_construct(input)
            gl_loss = gl_loss_from
            new_supports = resolution_static
            dy_adj = adp

        skip = self.skip0(F.dropout(x, self.dropout, training=self.training))
        x = self.start_conv(x)

        # Apply temporal embedding
        x = x.permute(0, 3, 2, 1)  # [batch_size, seq_length, num_nodes, channels]
        x = self.temporal_embedding(x, x.size(0))
        x = x.permute(0, 3, 2, 1)  # [batch_size, channels, num_nodes, seq_length]

        for i in range(self.layers):
            residual = x
            
            # Apply attention instead of dilated convolution
            x = x.permute(0, 3, 2, 1)  # [batch_size, seq_length, num_nodes, channels]
            x, _ = self.attention_layers[i](x, x, x, None)
            x = x.permute(0, 3, 2, 1)  # [batch_size, channels, num_nodes, seq_length]
            
            x = self.residual_convs[i](x)
            x = x + residual[:, :, :, -x.size(3):]
            x = self.norm[i](x, self.idx)
            
            s = self.skip_convs[i](x)
            skip = s + skip

            if self.gcn_bool:
                x_1 = self.gconv_1[i](x, dy_adj)
                x = x_1

        skip = self.skipE(x) + skip
        x = F.relu(skip)
        x = F.relu(self.end_conv_1(x))
        x = self.end_conv_2(x)
        return x, gl_loss, None, dy_adj

def make_model(DEVICE, num_of_d, nb_block, in_channels, K,
               nb_chev_filter, nb_time_filter, time_strides, adj_mx, adj_pa,
               adj_TMD, num_for_predict, len_input, num_of_vertices, d_model, d_k, d_v, n_heads):
    L_tilde = scaled_Laplacian(adj_mx)
    cheb_polynomials = [torch.from_numpy(i).type(torch.FloatTensor).to(DEVICE) for i in cheb_polynomial(L_tilde, K)]
    model = gwnet(DEVICE, num_of_vertices, dropout=0.3, gcn_bool=True, addaptadj=True,
                  in_dim=in_channels, out_dim=num_for_predict, residual_channels=nb_chev_filter,
                  dilation_channels=nb_chev_filter, skip_channels=nb_chev_filter * 8,
                  end_channels=nb_chev_filter * 16, layers=nb_block, seq_length=len_input,
                  embed_dim=10, dropout_ingc=0.5, eta=1, gamma=0.001, m=0.9,
                  batch_size=64, tc_dropout=0.1, n_heads=n_heads, d_model=d_model)

    for p in model.parameters():
        if p.dim() > 1:
            nn.init.xavier_uniform_(p)
        else:
            nn.init.uniform_(p)

    return model

here's the code for spatial dependencies extraction and graph construction:
import torch
from torch import nn
from layer_module import *
from torch.nn.utils import weight_norm


class calc_adj_5_withLoss_1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, node_dim, heads, head_dim, nodes=207, eta=1,
                 gamma=0.001, dropout=0.5, n_clusters=5):
        super(calc_adj_5_withLoss_1, self).__init__()

        self.D = heads * head_dim  # node_dim #
        self.heads = heads
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.eta = eta
        self.gamma = gamma

        self.head_dim = head_dim
        self.node_dim = node_dim
        self.nodes = nodes

        self.query = fc_layer(in_channels=node_dim, out_channels=self.D, need_layer_norm=False)
        self.key = fc_layer(in_channels=node_dim, out_channels=self.D, need_layer_norm=False)
        self.value = fc_layer(in_channels=node_dim, out_channels=self.D, need_layer_norm=False)
        self.mlp = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.heads, out_channels=self.heads, kernel_size=(1, 1), bias=True)

        self.bn = nn.LayerNorm(node_dim)
        self.bn1 = nn.LayerNorm(node_dim)
        self.w = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(nodes, node_dim)))
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.w.data, gain=1.414)
        self.attn_static = nn.LayerNorm(nodes)
        self.skip_norm = nn.LayerNorm(nodes)
        self.attn_norm = nn.LayerNorm(nodes)
        self.linear_norm = nn.LayerNorm(nodes)
        self.attn_linear = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(nodes, nodes)))
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.attn_linear.data, gain=1.414)
        self.attn_linear_1 = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(nodes, nodes)))
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.attn_linear_1.data, gain=1.414)
        self.static_inf_norm = nn.LayerNorm(nodes)
        self.attn_norm_1 = nn.LayerNorm(nodes)
        self.attn_norm_2 = nn.LayerNorm(nodes)

    def forward(self, nodevec1, input_gc, nodevec_dyStatic, batch_size=64):
        
        node_orginal = nodevec1
        nodevec1 = self.bn(nodevec1)
        
        static_graph_inf = self.static_inf_norm(torch.mm(nodevec_dyStatic, nodevec_dyStatic.transpose(1, 0)))

        batch_size, nodes, node_dim = batch_size, self.nodes, self.node_dim

        nodevec1_1 = torch.einsum('bnd, nl -> bnl', nodevec1, self.w) + nodevec1

        skip_atten = torch.einsum('bnd,bdm->bnm', nodevec1_1, nodevec1_1.transpose(-1, -2))
        skip_atten = self.skip_norm(skip_atten)
        
        nodevec1 = nodevec1.unsqueeze(1).transpose(1, -1)

        
        query = self.query(nodevec1)
        key = self.key(nodevec1)
        value = self.value(nodevec1)
        
        key = key.squeeze(-1).contiguous().view(batch_size, self.heads, self.head_dim, nodes)
        
        query = query.squeeze(-1).contiguous().view(batch_size, self.heads, self.head_dim, nodes).transpose(-1, -2)

        # attention = batch_size, heads, nodes, nodes
        attention = torch.einsum('bhnd, bhdu-> bhnu', [query, key])

        attention /= (self.head_dim ** 0.5)
        attention = F.dropout(attention, self.dropout, training=self.training)

        attention = self.mlp(attention) + attention

        
        resolution = self.attn_norm(torch.sum(attention, dim=1)) + skip_atten
        resolution1 = F.relu(torch.einsum('bnm, ml->bnl', [self.linear_norm(resolution), self.attn_linear]))

        resolution1 = torch.einsum('bnm, ml -> bnl', [resolution1, self.attn_linear_1])
        relation2 = self.attn_norm_1(resolution1 + resolution)
        relation2 = F.dropout(relation2, self.dropout, training=self.training)
        
        static_graph_inf = static_graph_inf.unsqueeze(0).repeat(batch_size, 1, 1)
        
        relation3 = self.attn_norm_2(relation2) + static_graph_inf
        
        relation4 = F.softmax(F.relu(relation3), dim=2)

        gl_loss = None
        if self.training:
            gl_loss = self.graph_loss_orginal(input_gc, relation4, self.eta, self.gamma)

        node_model = value
        return relation4, static_graph_inf, node_orginal, gl_loss, node_model, relation3

    def static_graph(self, nodevec):
        resolution_static = torch.mm(nodevec, nodevec.transpose(1, 0))
        resolution_static = F.softmax(F.relu(self.attn_static(resolution_static)), dim=1)
        return resolution_static

    def graph_loss_orginal(self, input, adj, eta=1, gamma=0.001):  # 0.0001
        
        B, N, D = input.shape
        x_i = input.unsqueeze(2).expand(B, N, N, D)
        x_j = input.unsqueeze(1).expand(B, N, N, D)
        dist_loss = torch.pow(torch.norm(x_i - x_j, dim=3), 2) * adj
        
        dist_loss = torch.sum(dist_loss, dim=(1, 2))

        f_norm = torch.pow(torch.norm(adj, dim=(1, 2)), 2)
        
        gl_loss = dist_loss + gamma * f_norm
        
        return gl_loss


class graph_constructor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nodes, dim, device, time_step, cout=16, heads=4, head_dim=8,
                 eta=1, gamma=0.0001, dropout=0.5, m=0.9, batch_size=64, in_dim=2, is_add1=True):
        super(graph_constructor, self).__init__()
        self.embed1 = nn.Embedding(nodes, dim)

        self.m = m
        self.embed2 = nn.Embedding(nodes, dim)
        for param in self.embed2.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
        for para_static, para_w in zip(self.embed2.parameters(), self.embed1.parameters()):
            para_static.data = para_w.data
        self.heads = heads
        self.head_dim = head_dim

        self.out_channel = cout
        self.device = device
        
        self.dim = dim
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.time_step = time_step
        if is_add1:
            time_length = time_step + 1
        else:
            time_length = time_step

        self.trans_Merge_line = nn.Conv2d(in_dim, dim, kernel_size=(1, time_length), bias=True) # cout
        self.gate_Fusion_1 = gatedFusion_1(self.dim, device)

        self.calc_adj = calc_adj_5_withLoss_1(node_dim=dim, heads=heads, head_dim=head_dim, nodes=nodes,
                                              eta=eta, gamma=gamma, dropout=dropout)

        self.dim_to_channels = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(heads * head_dim, cout * time_step)))
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.dim_to_channels.data, gain=1.414)
        self.skip_norm = nn.LayerNorm(time_step)
        self.time_norm = nn.LayerNorm(dim)

    def forward(self, input):
        """
        input = batch_size, 2, nodes ,time_step
        """
        batch_size, nodes, time_step = input.shape[0], self.nodes, self.time_step

        time_node = input
        # time_node_2 = b, n, dim
        
        time_node = self.time_norm(self.trans_Merge_line(time_node).squeeze(-1).transpose(1, 2))
        
        idx = torch.arange(self.nodes).to(self.device)
        nodevec1 = self.embed1(idx)
        nodevec_orginal = nodevec1
        
        nodevec1 = self.gate_Fusion_1(batch_size, nodevec1, time_node) + nodevec1 # time_node #
        
        adj = self.calc_adj(nodevec1, time_node, nodevec_orginal, batch_size)
        return adj

and here's the code for multi head self-attention:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

class ScaledDotProductAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_k, num_of_d):
        super(ScaledDotProductAttention, self).__init__()
        self.d_k = d_k
        self.num_of_d = num_of_d

    def forward(self, Q, K, V, attn_mask, res_att):
        scores = torch.matmul(Q, K.transpose(-1, -2)) / np.sqrt(self.d_k) + res_att
        if attn_mask is not None:
            scores.masked_fill_(attn_mask, -1e9)
        attn = F.softmax(scores, dim=-1)
        context = torch.matmul(attn, V)
        return context, scores

class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, DEVICE, d_model, d_k, d_v, n_heads, num_of_d):
        super(MultiHeadAttention, self).__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.d_k = d_k
        self.d_v = d_v
        self.n_heads = n_heads
        self.num_of_d = num_of_d
        self.DEVICE = DEVICE
        self.W_Q = nn.Linear(d_model, d_k * n_heads, bias=False)
        self.W_K = nn.Linear(d_model, d_k * n_heads, bias=False)
        self.W_V = nn.Linear(d_model, d_v * n_heads, bias=False)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(n_heads * d_v, d_model, bias=False)

    def forward(self, input_Q, input_K, input_V, attn_mask, res_att=None):
        residual, batch_size = input_Q, input_Q.size(0)
        Q = self.W_Q(input_Q).view(batch_size, self.num_of_d, -1, self.n_heads, self.d_k).transpose(2, 3)
        K = self.W_K(input_K).view(batch_size, self.num_of_d, -1, self.n_heads, self.d_k).transpose(2, 3)
        V = self.W_V(input_V).view(batch_size, self.num_of_d, -1, self.n_heads, self.d_v).transpose(2, 3)

        if attn_mask is not None:
            attn_mask = attn_mask.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, self.n_heads, 1, 1)

        context, res_attn = ScaledDotProductAttention(self.d_k, self.num_of_d)(Q, K, V, attn_mask, res_att)
        context = context.transpose(2, 3).reshape(batch_size, self.num_of_d, -1, self.n_heads * self.d_v)
        output = self.fc(context)
        return nn.LayerNorm(self.d_model).to(self.DEVICE)(output + residual), res_attn

class Embedding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nb_seq, d_Em, num_of_features, Etype):
        super(Embedding, self).__init__()
        self.nb_seq = nb_seq
        self.Etype = Etype
        self.num_of_features = num_of_features
        self.pos_embed = nn.Embedding(nb_seq, d_Em)
        self.norm = nn.LayerNorm(num_of_features)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(d_Em, num_of_features)

    def forward(self, x, batch_size):
        if self.Etype == 'T':
            pos = torch.arange(self.nb_seq, dtype=torch.long).to(x.device)
            pos = pos.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0).expand(batch_size, self.num_of_features, self.nb_seq)
            pos_embedding = self.pos_embed(pos)
            pos_embedding = pos_embedding.permute(0, 1, 3, 2)
            pos_embedding = self.linear(pos_embedding)
            embedding = x + pos_embedding
        else:
            pos = torch.arange(self.nb_seq, dtype=torch.long).to(x.device)
            pos = pos.unsqueeze(0).expand(batch_size, self.nb_seq)
            pos_embedding = self.pos_embed(pos)
            pos_embedding = self.linear(pos_embedding.transpose(1, 2)).transpose(1, 2)
            embedding = x + pos_embedding
        Emx = self.norm(embedding)
        return Emx

def make_model(DEVICE, num_of_d, nb_block, in_channels, K,
             nb_chev_filter, nb_time_filter, time_strides, adj_mx, adj_pa,
             adj_TMD, num_for_predict, len_input, num_of_vertices, d_model, d_k, d_v, n_heads):
    L_tilde = scaled_Laplacian(adj_mx)
    cheb_polynomials = [torch.from_numpy(i).type(torch.FloatTensor).to(DEVICE) for i in cheb_polynomial(L_tilde, K)]
    model = DSTAGNN_submodule(DEVICE, num_of_d, nb_block, in_channels,
                           K, nb_chev_filter, nb_time_filter, time_strides, cheb_polynomials,
                           adj_pa, adj_TMD, num_for_predict, len_input, num_of_vertices, d_model, d_k, d_v, n_heads)

    for p in model.parameters():
        if p.dim() > 1:
            nn.init.xavier_uniform_(p)
        else:
            nn.init.uniform_(p)

    return model

the PEMSD4 Dataset shaped:  (16992, 307, 1) i normalize the dataset by standard normalization and divide the data like this
Train:  (10173, 12, 307, 1)
Val:  (3375, 12, 307, 1)
Test:  (3375, 12, 307, 1)
Any advice on how to deal with this error would be much appreciated.

It is very hard to help you with such limited information. For one thing, you didn't show us the stack trace so we can't see which lines of code are troublesome. And you also haven't provided the data. It seems that you are working with public data and it appears to bere here: https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/s42kkc5hsw/1 . However the datasets there do not correspond in dimensions to what you say you have in your post.

This is not an easy problem to track down since we have neither the stack traces nor the data. To state the obvious, you have a shape mismatch somewhere. The file I found here, pemsd4.npz, has dimensions of (16992, 307, 3) suggesting the dataset contains 16992 time steps for 307 nodes, with 3 features per time step.
The OP mentions the input to the model should be shaped as (batch_size, seq_length, num_nodes, features), for example (64, 12, 307, 1) for training batches. This means only one feature is expected, and so if this is really the correct data then we need to reduce the feature dimension by selecting just one.. After preprocessing, I split the dataset into train/val/test sets and reshaped it accordingly. Here's an analysis of how shapes propagate through the model and where the problem likely lies.

1. Dataset Dimensions
After preprocessing, the data is reshaped as:

Training: (847, 12, 307, 1)
Validation: (281, 12, 307, 1)
Test: (287, 12, 307, 1)

These shapes match the model’s expectation of (batch_size, seq_length, num_nodes, features).

2. Tensor Flow Through the Model
Temporal Embedding

Input: (batch_size, seq_length, num_nodes, features) -> (64, 12, 307, 1).
After embedding, the output shape remains compatible.

Attention Layers

Input to Attention:

Queries ($Q$), Keys ($K$), and Values ($V$) are computed as linear projections of input.
Shapes: (batch_size, num_nodes, seq_length, d_k) for each.


Matrix Multiplications:

$Q \cdot K^T$: Shape (batch_size, num_nodes, seq_length, seq_length).
$S \cdot V$, where $S$ is the Scores matrix: Shape (batch_size, num_nodes, seq_length, d_k)



The runtime error raised is:
mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (131072x12 and 64x32)

which suggests:

mat1: Shape (batch_size * num_nodes, seq_length) = (64 * 307, 12) = (131072, 12).
mat2: Shape (d_model, d_k) or (64, 32).

The mismatch occurs because:

seq_length (12) is used as the second dimension of mat1.
d_k (32) is used as the first dimension of mat2.


Root Cause
The indicates that the problem likely arises in the attention mechanism, during the matrix multiplication between $Q$ and $K^T$. This could be due to:

Incorrect configuration of d_model, n_heads, or d_k:

Ensure d_k = d_model // n_heads.
Example: For d_model = 64 and n_heads = 8, d_k = 8.


Improper tensor reshaping or permutation before attention.


To fix this:

Ensure d_model, n_heads, and d_k are consistent:
d_model = 64
n_heads = 8
d_k = d_model // n_heads  # Should be 8


Align seq_length with expected dimensions:
If necessary, truncate or pad the input sequence:
input = input[:, :seq_length, :, :]  # Ensure seq_length matches model expectations


Correct Tensor Permutations:
Ensure tensors are properly permuted before attention:
x = x.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)  # [batch_size, num_nodes, seq_length, channels]




Summing Up
This issue likely stems from a mismatch in the seq_length and d_k dimensions during the attention mechanism. By validating configurations, inspecting tensor shapes, and ensuring proper reshaping, you should be able to identify and resolve the issue.
